# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in tic-tac-toe game

Tags: ruby, tic-tac-toe

I am building a Tic-Tac-Toe game to be played on the command line.

```
module TicTacToe
  class Player 
    attr_accessor :symbol

    def initialize(symbol)
      @symbol = symbol
    end

  end

  class Board 
    attr_reader :spaces

    def initialize
      @spaces = Array.new(9)
    end

    def to_s
      output = ""
      0.upto(8) do |position|
        output << "#{@spaces[position] || position}"
        case position % 3 
        when 0, 1 then output << " | "
        when 2 then output << "\n-----------\n" unless position == 8
        end
      end
      output
    end

    def space_available(cell, sym) 
      if spaces[cell].nil?
        spaces[cell] = sym
      else
        puts "Space unavailable"
      end
    end
  end

  class Game < Board 
    attr_reader :player1, :player2

    def initialize
      play_game
    end

    def play_game
      @player1 = Player.new("X")
      @player2 = Player.new("O")
      puts Board.new
      @current_turn = 1
      turn
    end

    def move(player)
      while victory != true
        puts "Where would you like to move?"
        choice = gets.chomp.to_i
        space_available(choice, player.symbol)
        puts Board
        @current_turn += 1
        turn
      end
    end

    def turn
      @current_turn.even? ? move(@player2) : move(@player1)
    end

    def victory
      #still working on this
    end

  end

end

puts TicTacToe::Game.new
```

The method that is to take a user's cell choice (`space_available`) and alter the array with their piece (`'X'` or `'O'`) is giving me an error. I can't find why my code is throwing this particular error.

Comment: also should be `puts self` instead of `puts Board`

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: @sawa the error read `tic_tac_toe.rb:34:in \`space_available': undefined method \`[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't call the parent constructor in your `Game` class, therefore `@spaces` is not initialized.

Your hierarchy decision is questionable, but to make it work, you can simply change the `Game` constructor to:

```
def initialize
  super
  play_game
end
```

Comment: Questionable at best :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, very much so :)

Comment: Thank you @ndn. This worked for me. This is out of scope of my question, but can you explain what you meant about the hierarchy? Are you referring to the Game class inheriting from the Board class?

Comment: @scobo, right. It doesn't make much sense for `Game` to be inheriting from `Board`. A `Game` might contain a board instead for example.

Comment: Could that be achieved by separating out `Player` and `Board` and using `require` to bring them in as elements of `Game`?

Comment: @scobo, well, you can separate them in different files and add them with `require`. But that was not my point. It was about OOP design. A game is not a board, it doesn't make much sense that it would inherit it. You should have used an instance variable instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `spaces[cell]`. The error is telling you that you are calling `[]` on nil, which means that `spaces` must be nil.

Perhaps you mean `@spaces`? Otherwise - you need to tell the program how `spaces` is defined and how it is initialized. A simple `spaces = {} unless spaces` would work

Another way of initialising your `spaces` variable would be to call super when you initialize the Game:

```
class Game < Board 
    attr_reader :player1, :player2

    def initialize
      super
      play_game
    end
    ...
```

Comment: Perhaps - but it's not initialized. Game subclass initializer does not call super